# Strict DOCTYPE affecting spacing between images

Tags: css, xhtml, doctype

I am having problems with my image spacing when I switched to XHTML Strict DOCTYPE.

The following code - which uses Yahoo's reset stylesheet to kill off all default browser padding - leaves a gap of about 4 pixels between the two images below but ONLY when I use the strict doctype. Why is this?

It is only a problem in Chrome and Firefox. IE doesn't show a single pixel between the two images.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
     href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.6.0/build/reset/reset-min.css">
</head>

<body>

<div><img src="http://www.catfacts.org/cat-facts.jpg" border="0"/></div>
<div><img src="http://www.catfacts.org/cat-facts.jpg" border="0"/></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using Peter's answer as a start the following fixes the problem:

```
img { vertical-align: bottom }
```

The reason this works is that the default for `vertical-align` is `baseline`, which equates to  the part of the text "above the line" where the dangly bits hang down (lower case g, q, etc all hang below this baseline).

So in order to leave room it was leaving 4px of space for these overhangs.

Hope that made sense.

Edit: Visual aid from [source site](http://www.brightlemon.com/web-design/blog/?cat=13)
[image]
<sub>(source: [brightlemon.com](http://www.brightlemon.com/web-design/blog/images/typography/basics-01.gif))</sub>

Comment: kinda made sense - and it works too. any known side effects of this? i guess i'll see if any of my other images look in the wrong place as i come to it. only thing i'm wondering about is if i ever have inline images in text such as bulletpoints - but then i can always use baseline there

Comment: be sure to also read the article mentioned by ionut (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Images,_Tables,_and_Mysterious_Gaps). it goes into great detail and talks about future fix

Answer (score 7):

More information about the misterious image gaps can be found here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Images,_Tables,_and_Mysterious_Gaps

Answer (score 3):

Using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) shows that it is the DIV that causes the spacing, rather than the image.

I set font-size: 0; for the top div and the gap goes away.

(Oddly, there is/should be an inherited font-size:0; from the body in the reset-min.css so not sure why this worked.)

Comment: well that works. i HATE it thought! is this the best i'm going to get? interstingly setting font-size:1 or font-size:1000 gives the same sized gap

Comment: seeing that gap disappear is quite a relief. and an even BIGGER relief to see the gap on my actual site disappear. i'm very curious as to any other solutions though so for now i'll leave the question unanswered

Comment: oh and i didn't mean i hate your answer - i just meant - well you know :-) i just reread my comment and i thought i sounded a little ungrateful!

Comment: Don't worry - I know what you mean. :)

Answer (score 2):

In strict doctypes, image becomes an inline element, and behaves like text. Hence you need to change its `vertical-align` property, or change its display property to `display: block`, or `display:inline-block`

Answer (score 0):

Trying to rule out common errors, I made the code pass validation by fixing no less than 8 validation errors.

Generally if a browser can't parse the document in the DOCTYPE given, results are unspecified.

It still doesn't work mind you, but here's the validating code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
     href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.6.0/build/reset/reset-min.css" />
    <title>Required</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div><img src="http://www.catfacts.org/cat-facts.jpg" alt="cat1" /></div>
    <div><img src="http://www.catfacts.org/cat-facts.jpg" alt="cat2" /></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks - even though it doesn't work. i should get in the habit of doing things like that

Comment: this isn't a common issue? most searches for this issue just yield advice about setting padding to 0 everywhere - which i've done

Answer (score 0):

The display:inline-block solution definitely did not work for me.

The vertical-align:bottom solution did work, but with one caveat: depending on the situation, there were images that I had to instead set to vertical-align:top

Answer (score 0):

Switching to loose standards instead of strict worked for me... kept the IE formatting that I required, but eliminated the odd image spacing in Firefox and Chrome.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko%27s_Almost_Standards_Mode

Used the line:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```