# Whitespace between table row(with image) and table row(with date)

Tags: html

I have search around regarding this whitespace area while coding with html. But I still cannot resolve mine. My problem is that there is always a whitespace after the image of abclogo no matter what i change in the table style. I would like to see the image unseparated from the next line which shows 31 July 2012

```
<table style="vertical-align: bottom; background-color: rgb(0, 136, 64); width: 100%;">
<tbody>
<tr>
        <a href="www.abc.com"><img style="border: 0; width:>800px;"alt="Logo of abc" src="abclogo.jpg"></a>           
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: right; padding-right: 15px;">31 July 2012</td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Make a jsfiddle showing your issue?

Comment: I'm assuming the `width:>` was a typo, but also why aren't you putting the `img` inside a `<td>`?

Comment: This is answered in the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489974/strict-doctype-affecting-spacing-between-images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0` to the table tag. Or use `border-collapse: collapse;`.

Also add `display: block;` to the image.

Answer (score 0):

Simply float the image to the left: **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/947YJ/1/)**.